# Activity.runOnUiThread(Runnable action) only updates view once

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-runonuithread

In my fragment, I have an `AlertDialog` and a Bluetooth connection manager. I want to update the AlertDialog with the new states of the Bluetooth connection process, so I used the `runOnUiThread(...)` method:

```
getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    void run() {
        interactor = new BluetoothInteractor(getActivity(), new OnBluetoothStatusChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void OnConnectionStopped() {
                alertDialog.setMessage("Disconnected.");
            }

            @Override
            public void OnConnectionStopping() {
                alertDialog.setMessage("Stopping connection...");
            }

            @Override
            public void OnConnectionStarting() {
                alertDialog.setMessage("Connecting to device...");
            }

            @Override
            public void OnConnectionStarted() {
                alertDialog.setMessage("Streaming data...");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

The first time I update the `AlertDialog` message (`OnConnectionStarting` event) everything works fine, but the second time I got `android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.`

What could be happening here?

Comment: did you solve your problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace with

```
interactor = new BluetoothInteractor(getActivity(), new OnBluetoothStatusChangedListener() {
       @Override
       public void OnConnectionStopped() {
           getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
               @Override
               void run() {
                   alertDialog.setMessage("Disconnected.");
               }
           });
       }
       @Override
       public void OnConnectionStopping() {
           getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
               @Override
               void run() {
                   alertDialog.setMessage("Stopping connection...");
               }
           });
       }
       @Override
       public void OnConnectionStarting() {
           getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
               @Override
               void run() {
                   alertDialog.setMessage("Connecting to device...");
               }
           });
       }
       @Override
       public void OnConnectionStarted() {
           getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
               @Override
               void run() {
                   alertDialog.setMessage("Streaming data...");
               }
           });
       }
   });
```